# How to use database replication in Prisma and NestJS

Tags: prisma, database-replication

Currently, I am working on a NestJS project where I am using Prisma as the [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and MySQL as the database.

But I am stuck now when I tried to use database replication in this project.

I need to use the database replication technique in this project, so that the system can gain some extra maintainability. Prisma [has introductory documentation on it](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/managing-databases/database-replication/database-replication-introduction).

I need to store the data in one database. Besides storing it in that database, I want a replication of the data in another database of another server from where I can read the data. So, I mean a database for writing and another for reading the data.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with Prisma in this context?

Comment: So, you want to specify different database URLs in prisma for read/write operations? https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/172